# Javascript Insert Into A Dictionary from Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a dictionary like this:

```
var dict = {};
```

and I have a variable like this:

```
var string = "Hello";
```

and I was wondering how I would insert a value into a dictionary, where the key is the variable. Like this.

```
var dict = {
    "Hello": "Bla Bla Bla"
};
```

I have tried

```
dict.`${string}` = "Bla Bla Bla";
```

but it just gives a syntax error,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dict[string] = "Hello";`

Comment: Or ES6 `{ [string]: "bla bla" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dict[string]` not `dict.'${string}'`

```js
var dict = {};
var string = "Hello";


dict[string] = "Bla Bla Bla";
console.log(dict);
```